# Placeholder Fragment / Main Activity android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have been searching for a while now, so I am going to ask. 
I created a new android project in Android Studio. It automatticaly generates a `activity_main.xml & fragment_main.xml` .
There is also a `MainActivity.java` generated containing a `public static class` for the fragment.

Because I'm new and wan't to see the bigger picture I wanted to seperate the two files but ever since that moment I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="genius.ds.config.app.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="genius.ds.config.app.PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

This is my `fragment_main.xml` (I believe the error is on line tools:context="..." )

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="genius.ds.config.app.PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tvDeviceId"
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceId"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativLayout>
```

Just to be sure :

`MainActivity.java` (I changed the extends from ActionBarActivity to FragmentActivity, it was suggested to me on this forum)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{...}
```

`PlaceholderFragment.java` (And I am importing the `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`)

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {...}
```

If you need to know more, i will be around to answer your questions :)

Thanx!

**Edit 1 - Full LogCat**
Link to a file, because SO had troubles formatting :) http://pastebin.com/qAy3Z2sU
*Full Fragment Name* : genius.ds.config.app.PlaceHolderFragment.java

*Full MainActivity Name* : genius.ds.config.app.MainActivity.java

Comment: 1. Please post the full LogCat 2. What is the full class names (including package) of the fragment?

Comment: Which one is line #9 ?

Comment: @keshav : the tools:context line in fragment_main

Comment: Can u post MainActivity here ?

Comment: I just created a new application, it works now..